# How to plot line graphs with time in Power BI

Tags: graph, powerbi, linechart

My table looks something like this:

| Location | TimeSlot | Mean Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New york | 22-02-15 22:00:00 | 22.40 |
| New york | 22-02-15 21:45:00 | 23.00 |
| New york | 22-02-15 21:30:00 | 22.00 |
| New york | 22-02-15 21:45:00 | 34.00 |

Basically the signal is every 15 minutes and the data go back 1year+

At the moment I have a line chart that I have done by putting the location, timeslot and mean rate into the field section. This works fine, but Im still getting used to the 'drill down'  + 'hierarchy' options, I feel like they dont work very well. They are always summing up my values which makes the plot line inaccurate. I have fixed this by choosing 'maximum' in the field section so that it show the highest value (mean rate) on a given day but this doesn't work as well for month or year.

Also, I don't like that I cant see the entire table in one view, you have to scroll across which can be hard to read when you want to assess trends etc. (Ive added a pic)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8u3d.png)

So my question, is there a different/better way of getting and displaying this line chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drop the date into the axis field and Power BI automatically creates a date hierarchy, use the dropdown on the date field and change it from "Date Hierarchy" to "Timeslot", i.e. the field name.

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wasnt sure if I was doing it correctly.

Comment: So, did it work? Do you still need help? If your question is resolved, please have the courtesy to mark the answer. That is how you can say "thank you" here.

Comment: it did work. I dont know how to mark the answer

Comment: It is explained in the [tour]. Click the check mark beside the answer that solved your issue.